# How do we solve the following DE $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{2x}{1 + 2y}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{2x}{1 + 2y}$$

I am only able to obtain the implicit solution:

$$y + y^{2} = x^{2} + C$$

Comment: You could use the quadratic formula on the result

Comment: I would complete the square.  y²+ y= x²+ C is y²+ y+ 1/4= (y+ 1/2)²= x²+ C+ 1/4.   [math]y+ 1/2= \pm\sqrt{x^2+ C[/math].  [math]x= -1/2\pm\sqrt{x^2+ C[/math].